# How do I ignore the action of appearence of actionSheet when holding down a link for a seconds in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have noticed that the app "Reeder" is using the `UIWebView` but ignores this event.
it displays a custom view instead of the original `UIActionSheet` view.

Comment: Would be very interested to find out, myself. The only ways I know of would violate App Store rules.

Comment: here is a greate post to handle similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258771/uiwebview-events-and-hold-to-select-copy

Comment: Does this tutorial help? (From the question you linked) http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/

Comment: I already checked it. that's just the beginning to catch the touch event but I have no Idea to ignore(hook) the hold event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution myself:

avoid using any `html tag <a></a>`, instead use javascript `onClick` to handle click event.

here is an example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.plaction = function(url) {
    window.location.href = url;
    // window.location = url;
};
</script>

<p> onclick="plaction('title:a::url:http://localhost:3000/toplists/2.xml')" class="name">contents<p>
```

Comment: So this only works on html that you load from within your app that you've written to use onClick events, right? Without using some hacky javascript rewrites, you couldn't use this solution on normal webpages.

Comment: right, most time it should work for your own app and own web pages. but for some app like rss reader, there must be some other ways to solve it.